# Prevent to download PDF, Video file using PHP

Tags: php, pdf, video, web

I am showing PDF, Video file preview in my web application, but i want to give only read access to users, no one can`t download PDF & video files, I want to prevent users, how can we prevent users to download it using PHP ? only they can view, please share you ideas as soon as.

Thanks

Comment: You can't do this. You probably need strong copyright and term of use agreements with your end users if you don't like sharing your media.

Comment: **It's not clear what you expect**. Do you want PHP to... (1) Disable _right-click to save_ option? (2) Hide/confuse the file URL so it's not obvious from just looking `<video`> tag? (3) To act as proxy (as middle-man between the file and user) so users only see links to PHP?. (4) Since I can see every data loaded by your site (including URLs) through the browser's Developer Tools, how do you see PHP stopping me from saving a link?

Answer (score 5):

Any content that is shown on the client's side, technically speaking, already downloaded to the user's machine. If the user is seeing the PDF file - it's already been downloaded.

For video: it's not that straightforward, you can organize a streaming of the video. It'll be fairly more complex for the user to download it as one file, but still, can be captured.